# Insert modules (*.ko) that have circular dependencies

Tags: linux, module, device-driver

I have three Linux kernel modules (`*.ko` files). They have circular dependencies like this:

- `mod1.ko` uses functions exported by `mod3.ko`
- `mod2.ko` uses functions exported by `mod1.ko`
- `mod3.ko` uses functions exported by `mod1.ko` and `mod2.ko`

I cannot load the first `mod1.ko` file because of "Unknown symbol" error. I also tried two other methods but I got the same error:

- load all modules at a time

  ```
  insmod mod1.ko mod2.ko mod3.ko
  ```
- Put these files in `/lib/modules/kernel_version/my_modules`, and run

  ```
  depmod kernel_version
  modprobe mod3
  ```

Can anyone help me please! Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about merge those three modules into one?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
Merging the modules was not a good solution in my case.

What I eventaully did was to add use callback function instead of the original function. And to registrate the function in the other module using registration  routines (need to use function pointer for that).

This has eliminated the dependency between the modules.

You can then insert the non-dependent module first, and the dependent module afterwards.